# Is there a manga based on Dragon Ball Heroes?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

I heard there was a manga based on the game Dragon Ball Heroes. If there is, is it in English, and does it contain the non-canon characters like Beat and SSJ4 Broly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an spin-off manga called [**Dragon Ball Heroes: Victory Mission**](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Heroes:_Victory_Mission) that has been running since October 20, 2012.

Beat appears a lot throughout the story, the only reference I could find on Broly was in chapter 9 when a Super Saiyan 3 Broly card is played. I couldn't find any licensed English translation. However there are some fan-translations.

The story takes place after the events of [Dragon Ball GT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball_GT).